# PL/SQL Regex search based on both characters and digits

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-like

I have a table `TA` which has a column `inv_ref` with has data as below.

```
inv_ref
----------
MX/3280/20
CT/3281/20
CT/3109/20
MX/3272/20
RF/3275/20
```

My requirement is to fetch whereas middle 4 digit number of `inv_ref` between 3270 to 3299 **also** begin with either **MX** and **CT**.

```
select * from TA where regexp_like(inv_ref, 'CT/32[7-9][0-9]/20')
```

Above query only returns **CT**, how can return both **CT** and **MX** related values omitting **RF**?

Comment: Hi, it is your table very big ?? do you only need CT and MX ? or you have more combinations and you only want to omit one ? . I mean,  if the table is not big, you could use an OR condition with two REGEXP_LIKE expressions

Comment: Hi, table itself is big, and I need only CT and MX values for the moment, values in this column can only begin with CT, MX and RF.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TA
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(inv_ref, '^(CT|MX)/32[7-9][0-9]/20$')
```

Then if you have the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TA ( inv_ref, is_valid ) AS
SELECT 'MX/3280/20', 'Valid' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CT/3281/20', 'Valid' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CT/3109/20', 'Invalid, number too low' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MX/3272/20', 'Valid' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RF/3275/20', 'Invalid, wrong start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CX/3299/20', 'Invalid, wrong start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MT/3270/20', 'Invalid, wrong start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ACT/3270/20', 'Invalid, wrong start' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> INV_REF    | IS_VALID
> :--------- | :-------
> MX/3280/20 | Valid   
> CT/3281/20 | Valid   
> MX/3272/20 | Valid
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=933bc3b3b46e419cd11261f176aa4684)*

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier to add virtual generated columns:

```
alter table your_table add (
  P1 generated always as (regexp_substr(inv_ref,'^[^/]+')),
  P2 generated always as (to_number(regexp_substr(inv_ref,'/(\d+)/',1,1,null,1))),
  P3 generated always as (regexp_substr(inv_ref,'[^/]+$'))
);
```

In this case you can use standard predicates on those columns. Moreover, you can even create indexes on those columns.

Full test case:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE ( inv_ref ) AS
SELECT 'MX/3280/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CT/3281/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CT/3109/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MX/3272/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RF/3275/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CX/3299/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MT/3270/20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ACT/3270/20' FROM DUAL;

alter table your_table add (
  P1 generated always as (regexp_substr(inv_ref,'^[^/]+')),
  P2 generated always as (to_number(regexp_substr(inv_ref,'/(\d+)/',1,1,null,1))),
  P3 generated always as (regexp_substr(inv_ref,'[^/]+$'))
);

select * from your_table
where p1 IN ('CT', 'MX')
  and p2 BETWEEN 3270 and 3299;
```

Result:

```
MX/3280/20  MX        3280 20
CT/3281/20  CT        3281 20
MX/3272/20  MX        3272 20
```

Comment: To answer the question you need a `WHERE` clause on the final select like `WHERE p1 IN ('CT', 'MX') AND p2 BETWEEN 3270 and 3299`.

Comment: @MT0 it was obvious, but ok, added :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
SQL> create table my_test ( inv_ref varchar2(100) ) ;

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'MX/3280/20') ;

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'CD/3281/20') ;

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'CD/3109/20') ;

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'MX/3272/20') ;

SQL> insert into my_test values ( 'RF/3275/20') ;

Table created.

SQL> SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.
```

Two options ( in my case I use CD instead of CT ). **This option will work as long as the strings are limited to the example. If you would have other combination it won't , as CD|MX means C or D or M or X** ). See comments to the answer. @MTO, Thanks for your comments.

```
SQL> select * from my_test where regexp_like(inv_ref, '[CD|MX]/32[7-9][0-9]/20')

INV_REF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MX/3280/20
CD/3281/20
MX/3272/20


SQL> select * from my_test where regexp_like(inv_ref, 'CD/32[7-9][0-9]/20') or 
regexp_like(inv_ref, 'MX/32[7-9][0-9]/20')

INV_REF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MX/3280/20
CD/3281/20
MX/3272/20
```

Comment: The first option is wrong. `[CD|MX]` will match a single character that is either `C` or `D` or `|` or `M` or `X`. It looks like it succeeds because you have not anchored it to the start of the string and it can match the `D` or the `X` but it matches too much. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cab7c93a685042dca6d9c9e233a86e8f)

Comment: If I enclosed the combinations, "CD"|"MX" it should work, right ?

Comment: No, it will now match a single character that is either `"` or `C` or `D` or `"` or `|` or `"` or `M` or `X` or `"`.

Comment: you are totally right. I will edit my answer to say that it would work as long as the combinations are limited. Thank you @MT0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values separated by `|` (or) as follows:

```
select * from TA where regexp_like(inv_ref, '^(CT|MX)/32[7-9][0-9]/20');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74af569adf480c043df61c567799ff35)

Comment: This is wrong. `[CT|MX]` will match a single character that is either `C` or `T` or `|` or `M` or `X`. It looks like it succeeds because you have not anchored it to the start of the string and it can match the `T` or the `X` but it matches too much. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab1c92aa37621674ef366dc7930446ee)

Comment: Still matches too much [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8e19be6247d58a2f412c68edb914937)

Comment: Just use ^(CT|MX). [abc] is is a "character class" that means "any character from a,b or c" (a character class may use ranges, e.g. [a-d] = [abcd])